# Custom Dropdownlist in Entity Form - Access field error CRM2011

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

I am implementing custom dropdown (select controls) in CRM 2011 entity form. The html of select control is in a html file which i imported as a webresource. I have added that webresource in entity form. Now in onload function, I am trying to populate that select control with some hard coded values but it shows following error when form loads:

[image]

Here is the onload function:

```
function onload()
{
var select = document.getElementById("WebResource_State").contentWindow.document.getElementById("state");
select.options[select.options.length] = new Option('Text 1', 'Value1');
}
```

The above error triggers on second line of this function. Please suggest what is missing.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Either your select doesn't have an options property, (maybe it needs to be a capital O?) or the options value doesn't have a length.  You can use F12 in IE to open up the debugger.  Put a break point on the second line, and when it hits, inspect what properties/methods are available on your select variable.